# React Native - Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, super, superclass

I want to build a super class which contains several methods cause I want to call them from different classes. Furthermore, I have the benefit of reducing code.

However, I get the error message "Super expression must either be null or a function"

This is one of my classes where I want to call the function `super.interface()` from the SuperScreen.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import { SuperScreen } from "./SuperScreen";

export default class HomeScreen extends SuperScreen {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      data: null,
      key: 15
    };
  }

render() {
    return super.interface();
  }
}
```

My SuperScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class SuperScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {}

  interface() {...}
}
```

However, I still get the message `Super expression must either be null or a function`. Why and how can I fix it?

Kind regards and Thank You

Comment: call super from within SuperScreen component constructor or completely avoid using the constructor

Comment: Both not working...

Comment: For anyone hitting that same error message after attempting to extend React.Component, make sure that you're using a `constructor` on your CustomComponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import is a bit messed up.
Remove the curly brackets from `SuperScreen` import because you exported SuperScreen class as default.

```
import SuperScreen from "./SuperScreen";
```

Or correct the export instead

```
export class SuperScreen extends Component
```

Comment: Thank you. Working! - What does the curly braces mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean curly brackets.

Comment: Thank you. But why do I have to remove them?